# Android GCM Notification Intent

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

In my app after receiving the notification i click on notification from notification center but the app is not redirected to the desired class through intent when the app is opened. But, when app is closed it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the scenario you want in your app you have to setup the pending intent which would take you to the desired class when you hit the notification.

Your Manifest file should look like this:

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".ResultActivity"
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Follow the instructions giving in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) which is Google's official documentation in order to experiment with the notification you have received in your device through GCM.